# Why is my While loop producing a repeat of the user’s input?

Tags: python, variables, while-loop

Edit: Thank you to everyone who commented, the solution was so simple. I had to delete the “print(understand)” at the bottom. To those asking why I didn’t do this or that, it’s because I have no idea what I’m doing, but I’ll get there.

---

In the while loop I have, an option is “yes” to lead to a variable’s output, but it’s also repeating the user’s “yes” input.

```
# Print list of input options
options = ("""
Here is a list of your options besides "yes" or "no":

  Help - Shows this list.

  Go Back - Head back to the previous room.
""")
help = ["help", "h", "options"]

# Go Back
go_back = ["go back", "back"]

# Yes
yes = ["yes", "y"]

# No
no = ["no", "n"]

Begin = lines = ["Story start"]


while True:
    understand = input("Do you understand?\n")
    if understand.lower() in help:
        print("\n")
        print(help)
        print("\n")
        continue
    elif understand.lower() in go_back:
            print("\nSorry, there's nowhere to go right now. Try again.\n")
        continue
    elif understand.lower() in yes:
        print("\n")
        print(Begin)
        break
    else:
        print(f"\nSorry, let's try this again.\n")
        continue

print(understand)
```

I apologize in advance, I’m very new to python and I don’t know how to format the question in this website.

I am asking the player if they understand previous instructions and when I test it using the “yes” variable, it outputs the “Begin” variable but for some reason it’s also repeating the user’s input “yes” afterwards. Like this:

```
Do you understand?
Yes

[‘Story start’]
Yes
```

I am unable to find why it’s reprinting “yes” after [‘Story start’].

Also, I am staying away from advanced methods right now as this is a small project I am doing for an online course

Thank you!

Comment: The last command in the script is `print(understand)` so this is where the last `yes` comes from.

Comment: 1) Why `print(help)` instead of `print(options)`? 2) Why `print(Begin)` in the loop, instead of *after* the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typed 'print(understand)' in last string. Also move print in line 31) Maybe you wanted it to be a function?

Answer (score 0):

```
Begin = lines = ["Story start"] #<--------------------- array


while True:
   understand = input("Do you understand?\n")
   if understand.lower() in help:
       print("\n")
       print(help)
       print("\n")
       continue
   elif understand.lower() in go_back:
 print("\nSorry, there's nowhere to go right now. Try again.\n")
        continue
    elif understand.lower() in yes: #<---------------- condition
        print("\n")
        print(Begin) #<------------- function
        break
    else:
        print(f"\nSorry, let's try this again.\n")
        continue

print(understand)

#You typed yes so it ran the function
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**